# Movie about a scientist inventing a formula that is wanted by a company

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched a movie during my time at the Dentist, but only caught the last ~30 mins of it.

It was about some scientist & how a man/ CEO/ company/ organization wants his invention.

**This was what I remembered:**

### *Scene 1*

*Scientist (main character, skinny, looks like in his 20s) mixes 2 liquids (both in long beakers), then releases them quickly, showing that the new reddish-pink blob can float*

Friend: "Wait... Don't they have everything now?"

Scientist: "No; I gave them everything but the main ingredient."

Friend: "Hahaha, I would pay money to see the look on -*that guy's*- face right now."

*Cuts to -*that guy*- wearing a nice suit in a greyish/formal room*

-That Guy- (bald): "So you're telling me, that we do not have the formula?"

### *Scene 2*

*Scientist walking down the street in the day, car pulls up, then gets thrown into said car*

*Gets threatened in car amidst yelling, something about a girl, then is thrown out*

### *Scene 3*

*Scene with the sky looking like the cosmos, mainly green/white*

Scientist (alone, thinks): "Up there they always win... Down here, we always lose"
(something like that)

### *Scene 4*

*Together with the girlfriend (who looks kinda like *Kirsten Dunst* in the movies), looks like the sun's about to set, happy end, scientist puts his hand on her stomach*

Roll credits.

Actors were mostly white, movie had nice music, probably made within the last few years. I say that, because looking at the visual effects in Scene 3 it was pretty good, like "Life of Pi" good.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It *was* Kirsten Dunst. You're looking for [Upside Down](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1374992/combined) from 2012.

> Adam is a seemingly ordinary guy in a very extraordinary universe. He lives humbly trying to make ends meet, but his romantic spirit holds on to the memory of a girl he loved once upon a time from another world, an inverted affluent world with its own gravity, directly above but beyond reach... a girl named Eden. Their childhood flirtation becomes an impossible love. But when he catches a glimpse of grownup Eden on television, nothing will get in the way of getting her back... Not even the law or science!

IIRC he invents a substance like the one you described that floats between the 2 worlds. Adam also says at some point:

> Up there, they always win. And down here, well, we always lose.

Here's the trailer: